# Fill Between Two Polar Curves with matplotlib fill_between

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have a feeling I'm going to be smacking my forehead on this one, but I'm trying to fill the *common interior* of two polar functions `r = 4 sin(2θ)` and `r = 2`.  It seems I'm getting the opposite of what I want.  Any ideas?

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

theta = np.arange(0, 2, 1./180)*np.pi
r = abs(4*np.sin(2*theta))
r2 = 2 + 0*theta

plt.polar(theta, r, lw=3)
plt.polar(theta, r2, lw=3)
plt.fill_between(theta, r, r2, alpha=0.2)
plt.show()
```

[image: Polar Plot]

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Perhaps compute the mininum of r and r2, and then fill between 0 and that minimum:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

theta = np.arange(0, 2, 1./180)*np.pi
r = abs(4*np.sin(2*theta))
r2 = 2 + 0*theta
r3 = np.minimum(r, r2)
plt.polar(theta, r, lw=3)
plt.polar(theta, r2, lw=3)
plt.fill_between(theta, 0, r3, alpha=0.2)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Beautiful.  Thank you. (smacks forehead)