# matplotlib: fill circular sector between two curves in a polar plot

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, polar-coordinates

So I have two curves `theta1(r)` and `theta2(r)`, where `r` is uniformly spaced between some two numbers (1 and 330 in this case). How can I fill the radial segment between the two curves?

I have considered adapting [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27229826/fill-between-two-polar-curves-with-matplotlib-fill-between) solution, but it does not seem useful out of the box. Provided solution relies on an inverse relation, `r(theta)`, which would be ambiguous and thus inapplicable in my case.

[image]

Comment: Can you clarify how exactly you want to fill between the curves? Do you want a triangle connecting the endpoints or an arc for example?

Comment: @tomjn I want a [circular sector](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circular_sector)

Comment: @tomjn Is my question clear now? I would appreciate some help beyond question formatting :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is to make a [`Polygon`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.patches.Polygon.html) of the circular sector

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.patches import Polygon
import numpy as np


fig, ax = plt.subplots(subplot_kw=dict(projection="polar"))

n = 330
r = np.arange(330)

# auto correlate random numbers (see comment below)
a = np.zeros(n) + np.add.accumulate(np.random.normal(0, np.pi / 180, size=n))
b = np.ones(n) * np.pi / 2 + np.add.accumulate(np.random.normal(0, np.pi / 180, size=n))

ax.plot(a, r)
ax.plot(b, r)

arc_theta = np.linspace(a[-1], b[-1], 101)
arc_r = np.ones_like(arc_theta) * 330

start = np.c_[a, r]
arc = np.c_[arc_theta, arc_r]
end = np.c_[b, r][::-1]

verts = np.concatenate([start, arc, end])

p = Polygon(verts, fc="purple", alpha=0.5)
ax.add_artist(p)

plt.show()
```

gives

[image]

Comment: Yes, this works great! Thanks a lot!
Perhaps you can autocorrelate your random numbers using
`rand = np.add.accumulate(np.random.normal(0, np.pi / 180, size=n))`, so that it is better visible that the purple curve actually fills in the oscillations. I've tried it and it works very nice

Comment: Nice suggestion! I've updated the answer. Just be careful that `arc_theta` also has to be updated so we draw the arc between the end points of the two lines.

Comment: Yes, I've noticed. Thanks for response again. This looks pretty cool